# How to see math.se in your own language?

Tags: support, languages, se-sites

Suppose that you know *only* very basic English. And you therefore have difficulties when understanding questions and answers on math.stackexchange.

And suppose that you would like this site to be in your original language.

How can you improve/adapt to the language problem?

---

My answer below doesn't work perfectly, but it provides a good approximation.

Answer (score 9):

By using Google translate. You copy the link of the page say [$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} dy dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4011437/int-01-int-0-sqrt1-x2-sqrt1-x2-y2-dy-dx) on Google translate, and then choose the language that you want to translate to. And then you click on the translated generated link and done. I learned this in the YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJKs0kYRP4w

Example

1. Czech

[image]

OR

2. Italian

[image]

Comment: Very good suggestion, allesia!